# Mailchimp : Automation Workflow does not trigger

Tags: triggers, automation, workflow, mailchimp

I've just done the setup for automation workflow for a client. I've set the first e-mail to be sent immediately after workflow is triggered so I could test. Unfortunately the e-mail doesn't arrive after optingin in through the welcome mail (set in Lists -> Signup forms). I've verified that I've set it correctly to trigger on subscription of the correct list. Anyone has an idea what could be the problem here? Many thanks in advance! Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Mailchimp can't seem to put together a reliable automation system. That's been my experience. I can't afford to assume things are working to find out that they are not.

I have just set up an automation and in one test run it delivered 3 out of 4 in the sequence. Sorry 3 out of 4 is not good enough.

Another automation test sign up it took 30 minutes for the first email with the freebie to deliver "immediately".

Another test sign-up it is an hour and no "immediate" 1st email. It's 9:00 pm and when I go into trouble-shoot it says it is in queue to be sent at 9:00 AM. That is AM of today. 12 hours ago is when it is due to be delivered !!!! I'm assuming it probably won't be delivered.

Your experience may vary, but this is not worth the hassle and unreliability. This is 2 years after your experience. Plenty of time to work out the kinks I would say.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution. The automation was on hold. :)

Comment: Where is that to be adjusted? You mean the Automation rule itself was paused and you resumed it? Or is there any need to enable automation in a global way? Can't find out why my automation is not firing at all...